# Can I bind to a service from another service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Can I bind to a Service from within another service, if so please advice me how. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not something I've tried so I can't say for certain but as `bindService(...)` is a method of `android.content.ContextWrapper` which `Service` extends, I'd say you do it the same way as from within an `Activity` (which also extends `ContextWrapper`).

Answer (score 0):

A `Service` is a `Context`. Meaning it bind the same with as with an `Activity` (which is also a `Context`).